# Whenever I open my WPF Solution Aero turns off, why? and how do I stop that from happening?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, windows-7, aero

Just opening a WPF solution (not a winforms or any other solution) will cause my OS (Win7) to turn off Aero, which gets kind of annoying

Is this a graphics card issue or something?

Comment: It's almost definitely a video card issue.  Check the event log.

Comment: video card driver issue... i had other issues with my computer and had to reformat, everything is working now as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WPF uses a Direct3D context to render its components. Does your problem happen with other Direct3D apps as well? Say like games and the like.

edit: This is most definitely not programming related by the way, should be migrated to another StackExchange list.

Comment: not sure, don't have any games on this machine.... i'll try to see if there is an upgrade to the drivers